# Nativescript squared buttons don't work

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I created a nativescript app with angular, where I have some buttons with a custom style, but I'm not able to create them realy squared.

My css is:

```
Button {
    font-size: 13;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #3c3d37;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    letter-spacing: .2;
    border-radius: 0;
}
Button:highlighted {
    background-color: #494a43;
}
```

[image]

In that image you can see a small border radius, but why? If I set `border-radius: 10;`, it works and I get rounded borders, but it seems that there is a min border radius of > 0.

Or is ther maby some other default style (shadow or something) which is setting that little border-radius

Comment: look at the computed css attributes in the inspector (for chrome like so: http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector) and check where it comes from.

Comment: !important isn't working...

Comment: how can I watch the xml content of my app?

Comment: `tns debug android` follow the on-screen instructions to open the inspector in Chrome, and open the Elements panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make the buttons perfectly squared with nativescript

Comment: thx! and why? so I have to use a `<Label>` and style it like a button to get a squared click element?

Comment: The buttons look just fine to me but if you'd rather opt for that then, ok. That should work too. Upvote please :)

Comment: That is not a proper answer. Care to elaborate when making such statements?

Answer (score 0):

*For Android*, you can achieve this in NativeScript (not 'with Nativescript') replacing the `backgroundDrawable` of the view:

```
var radius = myView.borderRadius.value; // this works only with px unit
var color = myView.backgroundColor.android;

var backgroundDrawable = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
backgroundDrawable.setShape(android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
backgroundDrawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
backgroundDrawable.setColor(color);

myView.nativeView.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
```